# Flutter BLE, start action if read value in Background

Tags: flutter, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can connect / read / write to my BLE device.

But how is it possible to start an action if the BTE-device sends me a string/info?

My aim is that the arduino device sends me the current status and if e.g. the App gets "alert" as status the app should show a Tooltip or something like that.

I hope this is possible, else I have to search for another Framework

Comment: Please add relevant code if possible. Are you asking for a popup kind of thing that shows up when your app is running and a piece of info is received?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any code....
my problem is not the tooltip or something like that.

I dont know how I can react to a String given by BLE and then check status/time or something what is sent by my arduino

Comment: Are you receiving the string properly? If so, you can use DateTime.now() to get the current time just after you receive the string to get the time. You can simply use if-else statements to check the string and trigger something.

Comment: sorry, my problem is how i can recognize, that a string is sent, or listening to BLE for the next answer...